# Social security disability benefits

Tags: united-states, social-security, disability

I read the following in my social security statement.

"Disability — If you become disabled before full retirement age, you can receive disability benefits after six months if you have:
—
**enough credits from earnings (depending on your age, you must have earned six to 20 of your credits in the three to 10 years before you became disabled); and ...**

Does this mean that if has been more than, say 10 years, since I last earned social security credits, I will not qualify for disability regardless of how many credits I have? What does the "depending on your age" clause mean in this regard? How does this requirement of "having earned 6 to 20 of your credits in the 3 to 10 years before you became disabled" depend on age?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It didn't take me long to find [this page](https://www.ssa.gov/benefits/retirement/planner/credits.html) by searching.

According to SSA, you have to pass a recent work test and a duration/length of work test. These are based on how many "credits" you have earned per year. In 2020, you earn 1 credit per every "$1410 of covered earnings" and you max out at 4 credits a year once you earn $5640. The dollar amount per credit changes every year.

For recent work:

> - Before age 24 - You may qualify if you have 6 credits earned in the 3-year period ending when your disability starts.
> - Age 24 to 31 – In general, you may qualify if you have credit for working half the time between age 21 and the time you become disabled.
>   As a general example, if you become disabled at age 27, you would need
>   3 years of work (12 credits) out of the past 6 years (between ages 21
>   and 27).
> - Age 31 or older - In general, you must have at least 20 credits in the 10-year period immediately before you become disabled.

For duration of work:

> ```
> If you become disabled...    Then you generally need...
> Before age 28                  1.5 years of work
> Age 30                         2 years
> Age 34                         3 years
> Age 38                         4 years
> Age 42                         5 years
> Age 44                         5.5 years
> Age 46                         6 years
> Age 48                         6.5 years
> Age 50                         7 years
> Age 52                         7.5 years
> Age 54                         8 years
> Age 56                         8.5 years
> Age 58                         9 years
> Age 60                         9.5 years
> ```

Comment: The recent work requirement makes the qualification for disability expire in a certain number of years after one has stopped working in the USA regardless of how many credits one has. That's surprising.

Comment: @user2371765 the logic is that if you haven't worked in many years, you don't need to start receiving disability payments to replace the income.

Comment: @mhoran_psprep What if one has moved to another country which does not have disability, works then for enough time for the US disability qualification to expire, and then becomes disabled? Also, if one has accumulated enough credits for only disability but not for social security, they don't get anything after the expiry of the disability qualification regardless of the number of credits they have.

Comment: @user2371765 sounds like something you should consider when deciding to live and  work in another country for an extended period of time.

Comment: @Kat How can one know everything beforehand? I just did not expect this. Generally, when you pay thousands of dollars into the system, you get/expect something in return. It's only natural. How can it be all-or-nothing? That the system is strained is another issue. But it is not fair that the law does not provision for the kind of situation in which I find myself.

Comment: @Kat You probably have a misunderstanding. I came to the USA for working - not the the other way round. I was an outsider who did not know about these rules. Neither was I made aware of them when I paid into the system. Now US regulation does not allow me to work in the USA any more which is perfectly fine. The USA has its own rules. But they can't just pilfer part of wages in this brazen fashion. Either they should give work rights and then impose social security taxes, or give limited rights and not impose social security taxes. They cannot both tax and not give the associated benefits.

Comment: @Kat So I was resident alien for tax purposes but when I cease to become a resident alien owing to rules made by the US government, I lose everything that I may have stood to gain had I been able to continue working in the USA. How is this my fault?